# Lightning web security

Tags: lws

We are in the process of executing the ESLint rules for enabling Lightning Web Security (LWC). We are following the below document to install the ESLint, which is working fine with the LWC component and not running for Aura Component getting this error

> ESLint couldn't find the config "@locker/eslint-config-locker/uncompiled" to extend from. Please check that the name of the config is correct.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/security-lwsec-tools-lint.html

Comment: Did you find the resolution for this?